# ggplot: Add geom_rect using categorical value for min and max values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very basic ggplot:

```
library(ggplot)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=manufacturer)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=1.8, xmax=3.0, ymin='audi', ymax='audi', fill='red'))
```

I'd like to add a bar from x axis values 1.8 to 3.0 only for the audi row on the y axis. Is there a way to achieve this in ggplot? Any help others can offer on this question would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you mock up what your expected output is? Either in paint / preview or by manually specifying the coordinates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done.  Categorical values are converted to integers for plotting, so you can either specify them as integers (`audi` is the first category, so integer is `1`), or, as I've done below, make a list of the category names and specify by name.

```
library(ggplot)
data("mpg")
man_list <- unique(mpg$manufacturer)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=manufacturer)) +
  geom_point() +
  # geom_rect(aes(xmin=1.8, xmax=3.0, ymin= "audi", ymax=lead("audi"), fill='red')) 
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = which(man_list=="audi")-0.5,
                ymax = which(man_list=="audi")+0.5,
                xmin=1.8,
                xmax=3,
                fill="red"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Building on @Greg's answer, I believe it is is safer to recreate the factor levels in the `aes` call in `geom_rect`. This is because it is the factor *levels* rather than the character strings that are coerced to integer.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=manufacturer)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = which(levels(as.factor(manufacturer))=="audi") -0.5,
                ymax = which(levels(as.factor(manufacturer))=="audi") +0.5,
                xmin=1.8,
                xmax=3,
                fill="red"))
```

[image]

This works even if the factor levels have been altered from default:

```
my.mpg <- mpg
my.mpg$manufacturer <-as.factor(my.mpg$manufacturer)
my.mpg$manufacturer <-factor(my.mpg$manufacturer,
                             levels = rev(levels(my.mpg$manufacturer)))
ggplot(my.mpg, aes(x=displ, y=manufacturer)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = which(levels(as.factor(manufacturer))=="audi") -0.5,
                ymax = which(levels(as.factor(manufacturer))=="audi") +0.5,
                xmin=1.8,
                xmax=3,
                fill="red"))
```

[image]

In contrast, the `which(unique(...))` method fails:

```
man_list <- unique(my.mpg$manufacturer)

ggplot(my.mpg, aes(x=displ, y=manufacturer)) +
  geom_point() +
  # geom_rect(aes(xmin=1.8, xmax=3.0, ymin= "audi", ymax=lead("audi"), fill='red')) 
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = which(man_list=="audi")-0.5,
                ymax = which(man_list=="audi")+0.5,
                xmin=1.8,
                xmax=3,
                fill="red"))
```

[image]